# How do I read the disk configuration with AHCI driver?

Tags: operating-system, ahci

Hi I'm learning OS and trying to follow a book to write a kernel.

The book using IDE to control disk, while I tried to use AHCI with MSI to make it easier and more efficient.

I successfully read/write information and issued MSI interrupt. But I do not know how to read the disk configuration, especially numbers of total sectors available.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to read from a CD/DVD (i.e. ATAPI device) or a HDD (ATA)?

Comment: @CRoemheld it's a HDD, emulated by qemu. I actually tested it and simply send a IDENTIFY_DEVICE(0xEC) FIS with a proper buff will do.......

Comment: Is your question still valid? Do you still need some help?

Comment: @CRoemheld currently my question is solved, thanks mate.

Comment: if you are familiar with AHCI and SATAPI, maybe you could help me out? I found your question while looking for an answer for mine.

Comment: @CRoemheld I did read the intel's mannual, but cannot say that I'm faminliar...... but post ur's and give me a link, I'll try lol......